# Sentence classification subjectivity/objectivity

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, classification

I want to classify sentences as objective or subjective.

For example :

Objective: Taipei 101 is the world's tallest building.

Subjective: Venus Williams is the greatest athlete of this decade.

I was thinking of using Naive Bayes as my classifier.

What data should I use for training?
I was thinking of news articles and wiki articles for objective sentences. 
For subjectivity, I was thinking of using a lot of books (since books tend to be more subjective).

Is this likely to work or am I thinking about this wrong? What accuracy can I expect? Which data will work best for training objective and subjective?

Comment: Could you explain a little more about how you're planning on selecting training examples? If you're just going to pull all of the sentences from a book or news article, this is unlikely to work, as news articles contain some subjective statements and books contain many objective statements. How are you going to select features from the sentences to train on?

Comment: Yes your absolutely right , this is unlikely to work if i pull all the sentences. you just answer the question. what about using only the **title of news articles**?

Comment: Create a basic system, have at least something that works and then improve it incrementally. Read some articles how other people achieved to make a system on this. I don't know what kind of answer you seek, because there is no only one solution for this.

Comment: If you were given examples of objective and subjective sentences in a language you do not speak (say, Arabic or Japanese), how many and what kind would you require before you would be reasonably competent at predicting this distinction? No googling or language learning. Me, I would expect to never get better under these criteria. I don't think you can expect a computer to do better.

Answer (score 3):

The best training data will be the same kind of data that you will really be classifying (from the same source). If you train on news article titles (as "objective") and book sentences (as "subjective"), then really you're learning a model to distinguish between news article titles and book sentences. If you then use this model to classify tweets (for example) as "subjective" or "objective", then you shouldn't expect good performance.

I would suggest that you manually label 1000 sentences from the actual kind of data that you will classify as being "subjective" or "objective". This will give you relevant and accurate training data, and may also teach you about your data and your problem. Then start with those 1000 sentences as training data, and measure your performance.